# predict() in tensorflowjs is not working as expected after conversion from python

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter, keras-cv

EDIT: Provided additional information based on the comment from @mrk

1. I use KerasCV RetinaNet to detect certain objects and then save it using:
   `model.save("saved_models/retinanet_model.keras")`

The model works fine in python.

2. I would like to use this model in nodejs; hence, converted it using:
   `tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=keras --output_format=tfjs_graph_model saved_models/retinanet_model.keras tfjs_models/retinanet_model`

- The conversion operation provides the following warning message:
  `WARNING:tensorflow:Compiled the loaded model, but the compiled metrics have yet to be built. 'model.compile_metrics' will be empty until you train or evaluate the model.`

3. I then load the model in nodejs using: `retinaNetModel = await tf.loadGraphModel("file://./tfjs_models/retinanet_model/model.json");`

However, the `retinaNetModel.predict()` does not match the original model output and cannot predict anything.

There are several observations I want to share, which make me think the model is not converted properly somehow; despite the fact that I only get a warning as opposed to an error.

- In python, if the model cannot find anything, I get -1 for bounding_box, classes, etc. However, in the tensorflowjs, it looks like I have random negative values. I get two Tensors as a response where the first tensor looks like containing bounding_box values and the second Tensor containing the class probabilities. For example, the second tensor has something like:

```
[
  [
    [ -4.490991592407227, -4.7061991691589355, -4.518319606781006 ],
    [ -4.743373394012451, -4.800686359405518, -4.49501371383667 ],
    ...
    [ -4.731906414031982, -4.996838569641113, -4.9045610427856445 ],
  ]
]
```

- Another unexpected behavior is related to the size of the output tensor values. In tensorflowjs, I get 76725 items/arrays for classes and bounding_boxes. Why such a high number? In python, the model generates 100 length arrays for bounding_box, classes, etc.

I use the same machine for all (training the RetinaNet, conversion and loading to tensorflowjs in nodejs).
`pip list | grep tensorflow` generates the following

```
tensorflow                     2.15.0
tensorflow-datasets            4.9.3
tensorflow-decision-forests    1.8.1
tensorflow-estimator           2.15.0
tensorflow-hub                 0.15.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem   0.34.0
tensorflow-macos               2.15.0
tensorflow-metadata            1.14.0
tensorflowjs                   4.14.0
```

I use the same image data. In fact I wrote the image array from python and read it in nodejs to make sure it is perfectly identical.
I reshaped the data array via
`let imageTensor = tf.tensor(pixeldata).reshape([640, 640, 3]);` as my image is 640x640.

Any advise/pointers that you might have would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Doug

Answer (score 0):

With the given information it is a little hard to give specific advice. However I would proceed as follows.

1. Check that your **data pipeline** works correct in the node.js environment.
2. Did the **model conversion** work out without issues - check your logs for errors and if none, also warnings.
3. Are you using a **compatible tensorflow.js** version for the converted model?
4. How does your **model output** look like, is there some postprocessing step missing?

If this does not solve your problem, the answers will definitely help us to help you.

Comment: Hi @mrk Thank you so much taking the time to answer. I provided additional context based on your feedback.